# JBoss Database Identity Propagation?

Tags: database, security, postgresql, jboss, kerberos

I've read how IBM's WebSphere can propagate the identity of a user back to a backend database (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0506_barghouthi/0506_barghouthi.html).  Does JBoss have similar functionality?  Ideally, I'd like to be able to login to my JBoss application using SPNEGO and propagate that identity back to a PostgreSQL database using Kerberos or some other mechanism.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article you've linked to could be used for that, but there are some caveats.

Having the app server re-authenticate as different users using Kerberos is probably not realistic. From my knowledge of Kerberos (admittedly limited), it is designed so that end-user interaction is required to do an actual authentication handshake. The user does the handshake with the app server over HTTP-- there isn't really a mechanism for asking them to re-authenticate with the DB itself.

You could use their hooks to issue "SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION TO ..." commands to PostgreSQL, though, if your app server performs its connections to the DB as a superuser. That doesn't actually re-authenticate, just changes the session authorisation role temporarily.

You could also use one of the myriad "store some session information in the DB" solutions (custom variables, PL/Perl etc global variables) and use their hooks to work with that. This is actually what their Oracle solution seems to do, it sets the client identifier which iirc is just a global variable in dbms_util somewhere that is included in views showing current sessions (and postgresql 9.0 has an "application name" that performs the same role)